# Is it possible to call Activator.CreateInstance on a type in an assembly that is not statically referenced?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, instantiation, activator

Is is possible to user `Activator.CreateInstance()` to instantiate a type given the `Type.FullName` and `Assembly Name` even though the assembly is not referenced by the executing assembly?

Comment: That's exactly what `CreateInstance` is for.  If it *were* referenced by the current assembly, you could just referenced it by type in code.

Comment: Yes, it is what it is meant to do, provided assembly binding succeeds (the target assembly is in the "executing folder", the GAC, etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, first you have to load the assembly.

Suppose you have a "plugins" folder to look into:

```
            foreach (FileInfo f in new DirectoryInfo("c:\\plugins").GetFiles("*.dll"))
            {
                System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(f.FullName);
            }
```

Now assemblies are loaded and you can create the type using Activator.CreateInstance.

Answer (score 0):

Yup. That is the beauty of Reflection. You can load the assembly by knowing it's name and then you can create a type that is declared within that assembly.